# Skip fields in Sunspot solr search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot-solr

I have implemented solr search in 2 places for my rails application(ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.4). I have indexed the fields for search and it is working correctly. Now i want to add one more field using which i can search in the 1st search bar but not in the second.How can i skip the field search in the 2nd one.Are there any exclude options as there are field options present. Same model is used for both the search and also the same code below.

Gem version

rsolr 0.12.1

sunspot (1.0.1)

```
search = Sunspot.search(Food) do
  keywords reference if reference.present?
  with(:vendor_id).any_of(vendor_ids) if vendor_ids.present?
  order_by :created_at, :desc
  paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)
end
```

Comment: yo yo Biju, i was searching for some thing in solr, and i came across this question (y)

Comment: @SagarBommidi ha ha ..so did u got the solution.

Comment: Yeah got finally some how :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this issue working as expected using

`keywords reference, :fields => [:user_name, :food_habits, :age] if reference.present?`

and `keywords reference, :fields => [:calorie_content, :user_name, :age] if vitamins.present?`

Comment: The `:fields` option is correct. The `keywords` method by default includes all `text` fields unless otherwise specified by that option.